# counting in a Linked List

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just want to make sure that my getCount function will work, because I have no idea how to test this to make sure it works could someone tell me how I would either test this function or what I did wrong? It is supposed to count the number of times a certain object has occurred in my linked list.

Here is the ListNode import

```
class ListNode(object):

    def __init__(self, item = None, link = None):

        '''creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link
        post: creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link'''

        self.item = item
        self.link = link
```

.

```
from ListNode import ListNode

class LinkedList(object):

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, seq=()):

        """ Pre: Creates a Linked List
        Post: Creates a list containing the items in the seq=()"""

        if seq == ():

            # If there is no items to be put into the list, then it creates an empty one.
            self.head = None

        else:

            # Creates a node for the first item.
            self.head = ListNode(seq[0], None)

            # If there are remaining items, then they're added while keeping track of the last node.
            last = self.head
            for item in seq[1:]:
                last.link = ListNode(item, None)
                last = last.link

        self.size = len(seq)

    def getCount(self, position):

        ''' This function counts the amount of times a certain item is in the Linked List.'''

        count = 0
        if self.head == position:
            count = 1
        if self.head.link is None:
            return count
        return count + getCount(self.head.link, position)

     def __copy__(self):

        ''' Post: Returns a new Linked List object that is a shallow copy of self.'''

        a = LinkedList()
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            a.append(node.item)
            node = node.link
        return a

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------

    def __iter__(self):

        return LinkedListIterator(self.head)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

class LinkedListIterator(object):

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, head):
        self.currnode = head

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------

    def next(self):
        if self.currnode is None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            item = self.currnode.item
            self.currnode = self.currnode.link
            return item

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hopefully I posted enough of my code for you guys to see the problem. I just want to find a way to test to see if my my count works and if it doesn't I need to know how to make it work.

Comment: What is `getCount` you call in `getCount`? Why is ListNode in a separate file?

Comment: Why are you counting based on `self.head` (a `ListNode` instance)? Shouldn't you be counting based on the `ListNode.item` value of each node instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters So what would that code look like? I'm sorry I don't know what i need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LinkedList.getCount()` method has several issues:

- It tries to count `self.head` if it is equal to `position`, but `self.head` is a *node*, an instance of `ListNode`. It'll never be equal to a value you want to count.
- It tries to use the method recursively, but there is no global `getCount()` function.

There is no need to use recursion here; just keep grabbing the next node from the 'current' until you run out, and compare against `node.item` each time:

```
def getCount(self, value):
    count = 0
    current = self.head

    while current is not None:
        if current.item == value:
            count += 1
        current = current.link

    return count
```

Comment: So if I had to also find the index would I pass position? For example: `def getIndex(self, position):` ? Or how would I go about that?

Comment: @CooperGay: you mean `getIndex()` returns the value at that index? Then use the same `while` loop, but use the counter to count what index you got at so far; when you reach the required index, return `current.item`.